# Publish WordPress Theme via Git

Tags: git, ubuntu

I want to be able to easily push a WordPress theme I am working on to my web server possibly via Git. What software do I need on my Ubuntu server and how do I set up my Mac to push to that server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need for this is `git` and `ssh`. For a better management maybe `gitosis`. If you need help setting this up, you should have a look at one of the many tutorials out there.

To push the theme into the docroot, there is quit a little more setup:

Create a bare git repository:

```
mkdir /path/to/my/bare.git
git init --bare /path/to/my/bare.git
```

Then put a `post-receive` hook under `/path/to/my/bare.git/hooks`
Use a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/my/typo/template git checkout -f
```

This will checkout the current version of the theme on every push to the server.

**EDIT:**
Using a bare repository and define the work tree on the checkout, has one simple aspect:
You wont have any git files in your WordPress installation.

Comment: use gitolite instead of gitosis as this is no longer currently developed.